# Pass a variable from one angular application to another

Tags: angular, session-storage

I have two angular applications launched in the same PaaS (OpenShift) and I need both of them to be able to access the same variable.

The problem is that when starting each application, in the `ngOnInit` of the `app.component.ts` i have a call to an authentication service of the user that initiates session.

Now I have been asked to make a new call to leave log traces when the user logs into the application. From one application you can access the other with a button (and vice versa) and of course, if I put the new call in the two applications, 2 login calls would be made when only 1 has to be made the first time.

What I want to do is that when the user logs into one of the applications, it has a variable that the other application can query to see if the user has already authenticated (`sessionStorage`, `localStorage` or something like this).

I tried to launch the 2 applications in my local, one in `http://localhost:4200` and another in `http://localhost:4300`, and see if when pressing the button that redirects to the other application (from the same tab) they shared the `sessionStorage`, but no.

Is there a way to pass a variable, boolean for example, between both applications? (Other than the URL)

Comment: Can you succinctly say what your end goal is here? Do you need the two apps to share a login, so that the remote server will recognize the same creds & not require separate logins? Or you already have that going, and you need to prevent each app from falsely recording that the user only just logged in? Or...?

Answer (score 0):

[SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) might be a solution. While its support is not that wide. Might be not good enough.